# FFMPEG+Icecast - playback stops after some time in <audio> element

Tags: ffmpeg, chromium, icecast

I’ve set up a looping .mp3 stream using instructions here: [Concatenate](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate) and icecast. Everything works great, it’s been running for months, however if I try to embed the stream in an audio element, the playback will stop after some time (1-5 min) until the user refreshes the page. If I play the stream directly from the browser or from a non-chromium based browser (iOS), playback does not stop. Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening?

This may be an issue with Chromium-based browsers, I’m not sure. It doesn’t happen on iOS. If you want to try and reproduce this yourself, try and play one of my streams from my website on a chromium-based browser - https://rubik.zip

Here is my ffmpeg prompt:

```
ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -nostdin -hide_banner -nostats -loglevel panic -re -f concat -safe 0 -i /var/www/audio/brainfuel.txt -f mp3 -b:a 128k -ar 44100 icecast://source:xxxx@localhost:8088/brainfuel
```

This is my first post on SU so please excuse any issues until I figure everything out.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the cause of the issue was a misconfigured listen socket. Removing `<shoutcast-mount>/stream</shoutcast-mount>` solves the issue.